# How to validate uniqueness in join table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have 3 models: Open House, Attendee, and Registration (Registration is a join model to allow attendees to register for open houses. A registration belongs to an Open House and an attendee).

How do I create a validation on the Open House model that prevents an Attendee from registering twice for the same Open House?

I'm a little confused because the :attendee_id is on the Registration rather than the Open House, and that is the attribute that defines uniqueness in this scenario. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are not validating the `OpenHouse` you are validating the `Registration`. `class Registration < ApplicationRecord; validates :attendee_id, uniqueness: {scope: :open_house_id}; end` seems like it should work.

Comment: To add onto @engineersmnky's comment, I would also create a unique index as well

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!